# Components for new designs

Tags: inductor

I'm replicating an open source pcba in order to learn how to build more complex PCBs and there is a part that is not recommended for new designs:

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TDK/VLS252012ET-4R7M?qs=uxmvvYJjMIsaASiY9mND9w%3D%3D

What would be the best part to replace it with?

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Have you visited the Manufacturers web site for this part? Might be a good place to start, sometimes the Manufacturer will recommend an alternate part.

Comment: If you want this question not to be closed, re-write it to ask something like how a replacement for an obsolescent inductor should be selected (i.e. what parameters have to be as good or better than an existing part for substitution to be most likely trouble-free).

Comment: The manufacturer recommends VLS252010CX-4R7M-1 as a replacement, but you still have to check the relevant specs to be sure it will work in your application.  Isat, Rdc, thermals, etc.  As @SpehroPefhany said start a new question asking about specs and giving some more info about your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if the design is solid you'd just use the part.  The part isn't recommended for *new* designs -- yours is not a new design.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is the best

Answer (score 3):

Don't replace it. You said that this is just a learning exercise, not something that is going to go into volume production, so the "not recommended for new designs" status is irrelevant to you. Just use the part specified.

Comment: Except as part of a learning exercise you might want to know how to replace an inductor that's NRND.  Other than that, the "don't replace it" answers make sense.